# how to change open sound file to play a sound file that have it

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I want to change this code so that instead of taking and playing an audio file when it is called in the program, when it is called it will play an audio file that has already been addressed to it.'
Please help, I'm in a hurry, thanks
in wpf

this is the code :

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "MP3 files (*.mp3)|*.mp3|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog`.ShowDialog() == true)
                mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));'
```

and this is the call to play this codes :

```
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

when I want to change it to my own I can not do it,
I want to be a sound player that just play a sound that I get to app''